# HTML radio button, choose from another Button

Tags: html, forms, button, hyperlink, radio-button

I need to select a radio button from a href link. I have 4 different packages for users to choose from and they are listed on the radio button.

I have an image for each package, now I want the related radio button to be selected when the user clicks the related image link.

So for e.g. User clicks Image 2 and the radio button is on option 2, 3 for 3, 4 for 4, etc.

Any direction would help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Javascript. This will probably be the easiest solution to your problem.

> $('#img1').click(function() {
>   $('#radio1').attr('checked', 'checked');
>   });

or

> $('#img1').click(function() {
>   $('#radio1').click();
>   });